# What is the linear force in a bicep compared to the force at the hand?

Tags: muscles, joints

So I know that like most joints, the bicep applies a force near to the pivot (the elbow) and creates a rotational torque in the elbow, this moving the lever, your forearm and hand. Due to the biceps close proximity to the pivot it at a considerable mechanical disadvantage compared to a downward force on the hand meaning linearly, muscle are a lot stronger than we think. Assume somehow you could take out a bicep, for example mine that has a max curl of 25kg dumbells, and hung it from an anchor point, removing the pivot. What would be the maximum linear force of that muscle? E.g. would it be 4x stronger than the torque in the elbow that's applied at the hand and therfore lift 100kg?

Sorry this question is a bit confusing. I really didn't know how to describe this hypothetical scenario. I hope you understand what I am trying to ask.

Comment: Are you essentially asking for the summed force of all myosin-actin cross bridges of an average bicep outside the context of the body?

Comment: Also, you must recognize that the strength of a person's bicep can vary greatly between different people -- wouldn't you expect such variability to also exist in terms of your question's scenario?

Comment: Lastly, given my two above comments, might I suggest you rewrite/rethink your question slightly differently? I suggest focusing on the pulling force of a single actin-myosin cross bridge. You could simply multiply whatever value that is upward based on some average number of cross bridges per sarcomere/myofilament/myofibril/fiber/fascicle

Answer (score 0):

My answer is in the context of my comments posted under the main question. I tried scaling up forces throughout the muscle. I probably flubbed one or more things, so check my math and suggest fixes!!

TL;DR: The max linear force of an average male bicep is ~**1600 Newtons**.

The longer explanation:

1. [VanBuren et al (1995)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1281938/) estimates ~0.2 pico-Newtons per cross-bridge.

> In a direct comparison between smooth and skeletal muscle myosin, the average force per cross-bridge was 0.8 and 0.2 pN, respectively. Surprisingly, smooth muscle myosin generates approximately 4 times greater average force per cross-bridge head than skeletal muscle myosin.

2. The multiplication*:

- Note: Muscle fiber anatomy has been detailed quite robustly: [AL-Khayat 2013](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3963759/), [Wang et al 2018](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6404781/), [Mijailovich et al. 2019](http://dx.doi.org/10.1085/jgp.201812165)
- [Ojima 2019](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6618170/) claims each [thick filament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myofilament) is formed of approximately 300 myosin heads. (though, I've seen less reputable sources [e.g., [here](https://www.britannica.com/science/muscle/The-myofibril)] suggest as high as 500 without further support).
- [Ojima 2019](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6618170/) also claim each thick filament is ~15nm in diameter and 1.6µm long. [AL-Khayat 2013](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3963759/) agrees on length, but suggests this could be as large as 30 nm in diameter. [Szikora et al 2022](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9140763/) claims the length is consistent/conserved around 1.65μm across vertebrates.

  - We'll stick with the minimum suggestions: 15 nm x 1.6µm.
  - Also, note that [AL-Khayat 2013](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3963759/) suggests actin filaments are ~10nm in diameter.
  - [Higuchi et al. 1991](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1852212/) suggest myosin heads are 19nm long,while [AL-Khayat 2013](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3963759/) suggests 15nm each.
- [Gerling & Brown 2013](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/joa.12074) found sarcomere lengths (at least in human latissimus dorsi) to have an average length of 2.7μm, while [Dasbiswas et al 2018](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rstb.2017.0114) suggests "The sarcomeres in relaxed human skeletal muscles are between 3.0 and 3.4 µm long, depending on the muscle sub-type." So, let's assume 3µm.
- Previously, the force produced by a skeletal muscle myofibril was assumed to depend on cross-sectional area alone and not on the number of active sarcomeres (because of their arrangement in series). However, [Mendoza & Rassier's (2020)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7176582/) results suggest that myofibril force is affected by intersarcomere dynamics *and* the number of active sarcomeres in series. As such, the *total* number of sarcomeres per volume of muscle is likely important.
- [AL-Khayat 2013](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3963759/) suggest vertebrate skeletal myofibrils are typically 1–2 μm diameter and 2–50 mm long.

  - Regarding Diameter:

    - [Smith & Plowman 2007](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-044306642-9.50005-8) note: "in regions where the thick and thin filaments overlap, each thick filament is surrounded by six thin filaments and each thin filament is surrounded by three thick filaments." If each thick filament is 15nm diameter, each thin filament is ~10nm in diameter, and each myosin head (i.e. space between filaments) is 15 nm, it would suggest each myosin and actin complex would be approximately 65nm in diameter. That would be a maximum of 15-30 actin-myosin complexes per diameter of myofibril. So let's stick with a conservative 15.
  - Regarding length:

    - If sarcomeres are an average of 3µm in length, 2–50 mm long myofibrils suggest an average of 667 - 16,667 sarcomeres per myofibril. The average is ~8600 sarcomeres per length.
  - Putting length and diameter together, this would suggest that each myofibril might contain 15 x 8600, or ~130,000 thick filaments on average.
- 130,000 x 300 = 39 million myosin heads per myofibril.
- [Chen et al 2017](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-323-28683-1.00001-1) state: "the number of myofibrils ranges from 50 per muscle fiber in the muscles of a fetus to approximately 2000 per fiber in the muscles of an untrained adult."

  - This would suggest 39 million x 2000, or 78 billion myosin heads per muscle fiber.
- There seems to be a couple hundred thousand fibers in human biceps:

  - [Klein et al 2003](https://doi.org/10.1002/mus.10386): "The estimated number of muscle fibers in the biceps ranged from 201,360–312,708 in the young men and 149,301–291,501 in the old men"
  - [MacDougall et al 1984](https://doi.org/10.1152/jappl.1984.57.5.1399): "There was a wide interindividual range for fiber numbers in biceps (172,085–418,884), but despite large differences in muscle size both bodybuilder groups possessed the same number of muscle fibers as the group of untrained controls"
  - The average is around 280,000 fibers per male bicep.
- 280,000 fibers x 178 billion myosin heads per muscle fiber = 2.2 quadrillion (2.2x10<sup>16</sup>) myosin heads in a biceps.
- This equates to 2x10<sup>-13</sup> N per cross-bridge x 2.2x10<sup>16</sup> cross-bridges possible, or 4400 Newtons.

3. But, [Mettikolla et al 2010](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2896876/) suggests only about 1/3 of cross-bridges are active at any time during isometric contraction:

> These results imply that cross-bridges interact with actin in bursts and suggest that during active period, on average 36% of cross-bridges are involved in force generation

This suggests we should divide our above outcome, 4400 N, by 36%:

**As a result, my math suggests ~1584 N per bicep**

---

*MAJOR CAVEAT: [Moo et al 2016](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphys.2016.00187/full) suggests that my above approach is faulty:

> Sarcomere lengths have been a crucial outcome measure for understanding and explaining basic muscle properties and muscle function. Sarcomere lengths for a given muscle are typically measured at a single spot, often in the mid-belly of the muscle, and at a given muscle length. It is then assumed implicitly that the sarcomere length measured at this single spot represents the sarcomere lengths at other locations within the muscle, and force-length, force-velocity, and power-velocity properties of muscles are often implied based on these single sarcomere length measurements. Although, intuitively appealing, this assumption is yet to be supported by systematic evidence

> We showed that sarcomere lengths varied substantially within small regions of the muscle and also for different sites across the entire [muscle]. Also, sarcomere elongations with muscle lengthening were non-uniform across the muscle, with the highest sarcomere stretches occurring near the myotendinous junction. We conclude that muscle mechanics derived from sarcomere length measured from a small region of a muscle may not well-represent the sarcomere length and associated functional properties of the entire muscle

Answer (score -1):

This link I found answers my intended question fairly well and simply.

https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-physics/chapter/9-6-forces-and-torques-in-muscles-and-joints/